# How to add a composite foreign key in liquibase?

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I've been struggling for some time now to figure out a way to create a **composite foreign key in liquibase**.

I have a table **A** which has a composite PK, let's say (**id1, id2**). I'm trying to make another table **B**, in which the **A.PK** is mapped as a **FK**.

I'm using *liquibase* with *YAML* and something doesn't seem to add up.

I've tried adding the FK when creating the table (so in the column tag)

```
- column:
    name: id1_id2
    type: int
    constraints:
       nullable: false
       foreignKeyName: fk_id1_id2
       references: A(id1, id2)
```

Unfortunately this syntax returns an error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns
```

Another thing that I've tried is creating the table first, with the column for the desired FK and try to add a FK constraint on that column. This doesn't throw any error but it does nothing (also the log for LB says "empty" in the description)

```
changes:
  - addForeignKeyContraint:
    baseColumnNames: id1, id2
    baseTableName: B
    constraintName: fb_id1_id2
    referencedColumnNames: id1, id2
    referencedTableName: A
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The first syntax is trying to create a single column and trying to associate it with two foreign columns?

Comment: I see your point, but I'm not sure how I can otherwise map a composite FK, and the liquibase documentation doesn't really help

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [addForeignKeyConstraint](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/add_foreign_key_constraint.html)? Something like this:

```
- changeSet:
    id: 1
    author: you
    changes:
    - addForeignKeyConstraint:
        baseColumnNames: id1, id2
        baseTableName: tableB
        constraintName: FK_tableB_tableA
        referencedColumnNames: id1, id2
        referencedTableName: tableA
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Liquibase, but here's how it is supposed to look like, as far as Oracle is concerned: if you want to create a composite foreign key (in the detail table), then it has to reference a composite primary key (in the master table).

Have a look at this example:

```
SQL> create table master
  2    (id_1 number,
  3     id_2 number,
  4     constraint pk_mas primary key (id_1, id_2));

Table created.

SQL> create table detail
  2    (id_det number constraint pk_det primary key,
  3     --
  4     id_1   number,
  5     id_2   number,
  6     constraint fk_det_mas foreign key (id_1, id_2) references master (id_1, id_2));

Table created.

SQL>
```

It just wouldn't work otherwise; that's why you got the error

> ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

because your detail table contained a single column (`id1_id2`) and tried to reference two columns in table A (`id1`, `id2`).

Comment: Thanks for this, I think this is the right solution regarding oracle, but I don't see how I could map this in liquibase **constraint fk_det_mas foreign key (id_1, id_2) references master (id_1, id_2));** I'll try. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, I don't know either, but I know that you can't map one column to two. Good luck!